# AndroidHttp Exception NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, google-api-java-client

Well am using eclipse to make an android app which accesses google calendar API
am getting a NoClassDefFoundError Exception whenever i tried to execute this method

```
private void setupCalendarConnection(final String accessToken) throws IOException {

    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();// Here where the exception 
    GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
    JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
```

also i tried to replace it with

> HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport () ;

and i got the same error

```
05-07 20:08:04.513: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.extensions.android2.AndroidHttp
```

From my knowledge in Java.. This exception means that the class am trying to access is not defined by classLoader ALTHOUGH i checked the dependencies and JAR files included and it is included and imported

So any clue about how can i solve this problem
Thank you in advance..

Eclipse 3.7 Indigo --- Google-java-client-api 1.8----Android ICS(4.0.3) Api lvl 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved when i headed for Netbeans instead of Eclipse and imported my Jars manually in the libs folder... automatically added to Project and it is running like a fire horse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build path in Eclipse via **Project** >> **Properties**, then **Java Build Path**. Under the tab **Order and Export**, tick the library you are importing.

Comment: Thank you @Jason for your reply..I tried your solution but unfortunately I have the same error

Comment: i tried it but am having another error preventing the app from running... 
(Exclamation mark on the project icon)